# using @push and @stack in Laravel Blade to change a route based on user

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

my site has about 6 different roles with a ton of routes , they all go like this:

admin.student.create
coordinator.student.create

Some users can do nearly what others can but with a few differences, i want to avoid having to copy/paste tons and tons of code in my views like so:

```
@if (Auth::user()->role->name == "SuperAdmin")
 <a href="{{route('admin.group.create')}}">New Group</a>
@elseif (Auth::user()->role->name == "AcademicAdmin")
 <a href="{{route('academic.group.create')}}">New Group</a>
@endif
```

What im trying to do is something like this:

```
<a href="{{route('@stack('users').group.create')}}">New Group</a>
```

and on my users.blade.php view

```
 @push
  @if (Auth::user()->role->name == "SuperAdmin")
   admin
  @elseif (Auth::user()->role->name == "AcademicAdmin")
   academic
  @endif
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest creating a service to simplify your view:

```
@inject('routeGenerator', 'App\Services\RouteGeneratorService')


<!-- your html -->
<a href="{{ $routeGenerator->make('group.create', auth()->user()) }}">New Group</a>
```

Like that you can make complex code to generate the route and keep your view simple.

Example of service (Service is just a fancy name for a basic PHP class):

```
<?php

namespace App\Services;

use App\User;

class RouteGeneratorService
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        // Inject dependencies here if needed
    }

    public function make(string $route, User $user) : string
    {
        $type = $this->getUserType($user);

        return route("$type.$route");
    }

    public function getUserType(User $user) : string
    {
        switch ($user->role->name) {
            case 'SuperAdmin':
                return 'admin';
            case 'AcademicAdmin':
                return 'academic';
                // and so on..
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: oh good idea! can you please show a little example of what should go on the service? (kinda new to laravel) - btw using 5.2 Thanks a lot

Comment: Excellent!  you are my new personal Hero, thanks a lot.

Just to add a little bit to the answer: the correct html would be:

     <a href="{{ route($routeGenerator->make('student.create', auth()->user())) }}" >New Group</a> 

That way the route will work 100%

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Whoops sorry I forgot to call route(), I would rather call it in the service to avoid writing it every time in the view

Comment: True, great idea. Also, if i wanted to call it from all my views (about 100), would i need to add the @inject to all of them? since adding it to the base layout is not working.

Comment: You can use a view composer to inject the service (or any variables) in multiple view at once: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/views#view-composers

Comment: Hmm now i encounter a new issue, Is there a way to call the 

$routeGenerator->make('group.create', auth()->user()) from the controller? since i have a lot of   return redirect()->route(admin.x)

Comment: Sure, a Service is just a class you can call it from where you want, You can call the service by injecting it in your model or creating the service instance by yourself, or event registering it in the IOC container

Comment: Hmm when i try to run it in php 5.3 i get this error:  (on 7.0 works fine) 

FatalErrorException in RouteGeneratorService.php line 14:
syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ';' or '{'   

thats the 

 public function make(string $route, User $user) : string 

line

Comment: It works fine if i remove the type definitions like string $variable. But don't know if that's the best way to do it.